# How to create a dynamic external content type (the DB tables can change)

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, external-content-type

I want to create an external content type based on SQL Server tables. My external content is a list of Cats and its source is a database table also named Cats.

However, I have a different Cats table in different database catalogues (the name of the table might also vary slightly) and I would like to be able, at runtime (if possible), to change the catalog and table name, the external entity is associated to. Is this possible?

I'm using Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need to update data, why don't you opt for creating a View as the source of your data, then via SharePoint Designer 2010 you could effectively build your entity based on view.

As an alternative, more complex though is to create you entities based on Stored Procedures, have a look here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jysaikia/archive/2010/12/15/a-step-by-step-guide-in-designing-bcs-entities-by-using-a-sql-stored-procedure.aspx or here http://karthickmicrosoft.blogspot.ch/2011/04/using-external-content-types-with.html

In either case you would need to simply update your views and stored procedures, major constraint here would be to keep the structure the same - that is same columns, same data types and it should be fine.

Comment: Stored Procedure seems to be the way.